# Are there any guides or walkthrough to Two Worlds 2 Castle Defense?

Tags: two-worlds-2

I can't get past the first level on Two Worlds 2 Castle Defense (http://store.steampowered.com/app/7530/ or http://www.twoworlds2.com/cd/about-en.html - DEMO), I die in 9th round or so and I have tried already many different combinations with no success at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By first level, you mean the Oswaroth's battle right? Here is my final combination:

- Hero attack lv+2
- 2 priest heal lv+2 each
- 2 fire mage attack Lv+2 - HP Lv2 each
- 1 royal guardian  HP lv 3, attack lv 3

I already passed that level. Good luck!

Comment: If you get to pass other levels, please adjust your answer accordingly!